# Act on condition in custom loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, neural-network, loss-function

I'm defining a model in tensorflow, and as loss function I coded my own custom loss function. In general, I put a penalty term in addition to the normal MSE function:

`return K.mean(K.square(y_true - y_pred)) + penalty`

where this penalty is given by products and sums between some inputs elements and some targets (I do not report the code because it is unrelated to the question).

Now, everything works perfectly, but I need to add to the dataset a new kind of examples, where some features and output have zero value.

So, taking in the batch (during the training) both type of examples, i.e. with zero values and without them, I need a kind of conditional statement applied on the entire batch, so that I can compute the `penalty` in two different ways based on the evaluation of the condition.

Can it be done ?

Comment: Seems like you're looking for [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond)

Comment: Yes exactly, but I'm not so sure I can use it on a batch. Or if I can use it on a batch, I do not think I can apply different computations on different batch elements based only on the result of tf.cond. I was thinking on a sort of loop over the batch elements, and then on each a tf.cond, but I did not find anything like that around

Comment: Post a simple example of what you want to do, and I'll see if I can help.

Comment: Ok I'll clean a bit my custom loss so we do not need any background knowledge, and edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`tf.where`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where) :

For example:

- If element is zero, returns itself
- If element is not zero, returns istself + 1

```
>>> batch_1 = tf.constant([0.,1.,0.,0.5,3.,-2.,0.])
>>> tf.where(batch_1 == 0, batch_1, batch_1+1)
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(7,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0. , 2. , 0. , 1.5, 4. , -1. , 0. ], dtype=float32)>
```

---

It works too, with multiple dimensions tensors, for example:

- If second element of the batch is zero, sum the first element
- Otherwise, sum the whole batch

```
>>> a = tf.constant([[1,0,3],[3,4,9],,[8,0,1]],tf.float32)
>>> tf.where(a[:,1]==0,tf.reduce_sum(a[:,:1],axis=1), tf.reduce_sum(a,axis=1))
<tf.Tensor: shape=(3,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([ 1., 16.,  8.], dtype=float32)>
```

Comment: Probably I'm close! But I'm need something like "IF the 5th elements is 0, then DO op1; sum(only first five elements); ELSE DO op1; sum all the elements".
Op1 is just something manipulation the data, but doing so change what before was zero.

Comment: I added a second example. Let me know if it's clearer.